# LiveCD with VLC, TrueCrypt and Tor

Tags: ubuntu, livecd, bartpe

Is there a live CD available which has this Software installed or do I have to create my custom live CD? I tested the JonDo live DVD but some applications are missing. If I have to create a custom one, which is the best OS for that? BartPE, Ubuntu, ...?

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon which softwares you want, there is an live distro based on windows which includes lots of softwares, Its [Hiren Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), If you need more softwares, then you can create live cd as per your requirement, for linux, I will suggest for UCK(ubuntu customization kit) and for Windows BartPE is best, for bootloader, you can use isolinux.